# writing large multidimensional list to single cell in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a multi-dimensional lists to a single cell in CSV. I am writing in Python 2.7. My code looks like:

```
import csv
import itertools
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

csv_data = np.random.randint(50,size=(132,132))
csv_name = "some_file_name.csv"
path = "some_path_name"
os.chdir(path)
open_mode = 'wb'
args = {"name": csv_name, "mode": open_mode}
with open(**args) as my_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(itertools.izip(csv_data))
```

I have many more entries to write, but I only included one cell for readability.  When the size of the numpy array is roughly (132,4), there is no issue with entries spilling over to other cells, but with larger sizes such as (132,132), it spills over. I have tried casting the datat to a string to force it to stay in one cell, but it still spills over.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tried this, the result looks fine. The cell spills onto multiple lines, but it's in quotes so it's a single cell.

Comment: Note that Excel has a hard limit of 32768 bytes in a cell.

Comment: @Barmar, I am not sure how you ran the code, but when I did, all of the entries were on different lines. I even tried casting the numpy array as a string and the same thing happened. What does yours look like?

Comment: I ran it in the python REPL, and used `writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)` to see the output on the terminal.

Comment: The output looked like `"[25 numbers \n 25 numbers \n 25 numbers \n 25 numbers \n 25 numbers \n 7 numbers]"` where `\n` was an actual newline.

Comment: oh, yeah the file looks fine when i open it with notepad++ or something else. it's simply the formatting once i open it in excel. which makes sense, since a 132x132 numpy array has a size of 69752 bytes. do either of you have a suggestion for getting it formatted properly to excel then?

Comment: if the problem is with opening it in a spreadsheet application, it may be a limitation of that application.

Comment: by changing the csv_data to csv_data = np.random.randint(50,size=(132,132)).tolist(), the size in bytes should be 564; yet the excel formatting is still as such. [1x132] in A1, [1x132] in A2,...,all the way to row 132.

Comment: It's probably the \n which Excel is helpfully moving to the next cell - so try removing them. Or try inserting a linebreak in a cell (alt-return) and exporting to CSV see how Excel does it? And there's no (as in zero, null, nada, zilch) way around the 32768 character limit in Excel - no warning, you have to guard against it yourself..